# Flask-SocketIO app not deploing to Railway - tcp protocol error

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am trying to deploy an app that is working fine locally, but in Railway the build fails:

```
Error: class uri 'eventlet' invalid or not found:
[Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 99, in load_class
mod = importlib.import_module('.'.join(components))
File "/nix/store/dcy4s05wgyznzcvghsm1sgbf7a0xrp8k-python3-3.9.13/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 12, in <module>
import eventlet
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from eventlet import convenience
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 7, in <module>
from eventlet.green import socket
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/green/socket.py", line 21, in <module>
from eventlet.support import greendns
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 71, in <module>
setattr(dns.rdtypes.IN, pkg, import_patched('dns.rdtypes.IN.' + pkg))
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/support/greendns.py", line 61, in import_patched
return patcher.import_patched(module_name, **modules)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 132, in import_patched
return inject(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eventlet/patcher.py", line 109, in inject
module = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, module_name.split('.')[:-1])
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dns/rdtypes/IN/WKS.py", line 25, in <module>
_proto_tcp = socket.getprotobyname('tcp')
OSError: protocol not found
]
```

Since it works on my PC (running Mac OS), I am assuming it's a configuration error. I tried different Procfiles, like

`web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT} wsgi:app`

and

`web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app`, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Best course of action is to google the error message. I got this link that appears to be useful for your problem: https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/370